# Debian pm2 unable to start elasticsearch server

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, debian, pm2

I'm running a node server on a linux debian core.
I'm using [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) to run all processes in the background and monitor them.
Everything is working properly except the elasticsearch server, I'm getting an error message which I do not understand.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function._load (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/pmx/lib/transaction.js:62:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:46:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
```

When i do `pm2 list` to view the other processes, this is the result:

[image]

The command i use to start the elasticsearch server is simply `pm2 start ./bin/elasticsearch` instead of `./bin/elasticsearch` which is what the docs says.

I'm going to run the elasticsearch server locally only so the correct ip is `127.0.0.1` port `9200`.
I should also mention that the elasticsearch server **DO** work if i run it normally, without pm2.

Here is my elasticsearch.yml configuration file.

```
cluster.name: swissnet
node.name: "swissnet-data"
node.master: true
node.data: true
path.data: ../local-data/
path.logs: ../local-logs/
ES_HEAP_SIZE: 300m
network.host: 127.0.0.1
http.port: 9200
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["127.0.0.1"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
gateway.recover_after_nodes: 8
gateway.expected_nodes: 10
gateway.recover_after_time: 5m
ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Des.insecure.allow.root=true"
```

Any ideas? Elasticsearch.yml updates are also welcome.

Comment: Is there anything useful available in your ES log file?

Comment: The log file just repeats the `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` error message, that's all i get unfortunately. Or that's the pm2 error log for ES, the ES log doesn't update when i run `pm2 start ./bin/elasticsearch`. Not a single row.

Comment: But that's not the elasticsearch log file. Can you check in `../local-logs/swissnet.log` ?

Comment: Sorry, updated my earlier response

Comment: Looks like a pm2 bug: https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/issues/1618

Comment: Does not seem to be resolved tho, tried the latest dev version and updated as mentioned in the comments, but the issue remains. Hopefully someone will stumble across this thread whom have solved this issue.

Comment: Did you copy/paste the ES config from somewhere by any chance? Sometimes, copy/pasting introduces illegal characters which are not visible but wreak havoc in some way or another.

Comment: I edited the config file on a mac osx and used git to implement it on the server. I'll try to rewrite the config file manually in the linux terminal.

Comment: Getting the same error unfortunately :/

Answer (score 3):

You need create file sh, for example: ES_service.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
sh /your_path/bin/elasticsearch
```

then run your pm2 command:

```
pm2 start ES_service.sh --name=elasticsearch
```

check your service with pm2 list
I was used it in Ubuntu and Centos 7, everything ok
maybe it help

Regards